# Records in lightning flow needs to save between screen

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have a Screen flow and I wanted the user to save the data and later retrieve without loosing the entered data. There are multiple screen component and the user has to complete in order to be submitted for next process. But User would get a chance to edit the data before it has been submitted. Suppose there are 10 screens, and user entered only data in 2 screens and wanted to exit the flow but need to save up to that screen. Also there are some required fields also, but that are on the next screens. How do I save in between. The user doesn't want to go to a separate screen and input their choice in order to be advanced for the next step. What is the best option. The Flows's "Pause" option only works in Autolaunched Flow.

Comment: The Pause option should work in screen flow, it has to be enabled in Automation settings. Are you having any issues with that? Pause element is not available for screen flows as it waits for a specific time. These are 2 different things.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that case, if I Paused and come back the next day, the flow should continue from where we paused?

Comment: I tested the pause. It works. But when the user paused, we should not allow them to go to setup and go to paused interview and resume from there. How can we use a better way to resume, like click button etc.

Comment: You might need to use Apex for that or try using the actions and recommendations components https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_pausedid.htm

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I have already started how to use Actions & Recommendations. If any problems comes in, I would let you know. Thanks